# Magento product->setPrice doesn't work in Event Observer Product collection load after

Tags: php, magento, events, collections, set

I've got an observer which changes the prices of products in the product list and the product view. To realize that i'm using the catalogProductLoadAfter and the catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter events.

```
public function catalogProductLoadAfter( $observer )
{
        $product    = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product->setPrice( 123.00 );
}


public function catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter( $observer )
{
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product)
        {
               $product->setPrice(123.00); // doesn't work
        }
}
```

The catalogProductLoadAfter $product->setPrice works fine, but in catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter it does nothing... no error, no changing, nothing. What did i wrong Oo ?! Is there any magic i've to use or is that a magento bug ?

I've worked for a company which had such an observer too and there only works the catalogProductLoadAfter setPrice too and not the catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter setPrice.

I'm using the Trego Design and the Simple Configurable Product Plugin which has an AJAX product updater.. Is it possible that there are conflicts, maybe the trego plugins or the SCP Plugin overrides the prices too ?

//Edit: i searched for any setPrice uses, nothing found which can create conflicts.. no extern actions from other modules

Thanks for any help.

Greetings

Comment: dear i have same issue please help. the below answer is not work for me thank's

Comment: Hey there today,

I got it running with a solution which isn't very comfortable. Every time the catalogProductcollectionLoafAfter Event is called i set up the price new with an individual variable like $product->setData('mynewprice', 123.00); . So, the issue that $product->setPrice won't work in catalog view is solved by editing the price.phtml of your design. just replace the $_price = (some mage code to read out price) to $_price = $product->getData('mynewprice'). Also the finalprice has to be set. This could work for you too... It's a very bad answer for that problem but it does its job.

Comment: For your cart you have to add the productaddcart after event and set  the item custom- and originalcustomprice easily to the getData('mynewprice') of the specific product (get it with $item->getProduct()) and the product to supermode

Comment: I'm glad that it is working for you. No problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function catalogProductCollectionLoadAfter( $observer )
{
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product)
        {
               $product->setData('my_price','123.00');
        }
}
```

You can retrieve the price value like below:

`$product->getMyPrice();`

**OR**

```
$product->getData('my_price');
```

Comment: Thank u but it doesn't work.

save() crashes the whole shop and setData does nothing too.

the changes of the prices shoudn't be saved in database ! It has to be shown temporarily in the product list view.

Another way to realize what i want ? 

Thanks

Comment: Thank u. This is a way to do it, but if i do so, i've to edit Mage Core files like price.php and i don't want to do that. I only want to temporarily edit the price which will be shown in the collection view via the Mage getPrice function. So i want to use setPrice which function i used in the catalogProductLoadAfter too where it works.

//Edit: If i use setFinalPrice, it works but shows me the new price like "old price: 234    PriceFrom 123.00"

Comment: You are not editing core files but setting your custom value in session and then fetching it later.

Comment: hrrrrr isn't there a way to do it with setPrice like i do in the normal product view... ? All of the other ways are so complicated.

Thanks

Comment: //I've solved it with your way to set optional data like $product->setData('myprise', 123); . In list.phtml of my template i read out the Data whether it's set or not. If so, the $_price variable will be set to.

Thanks for your help